# Square of a finite sum

Tags: summation, summation-method

In order to carry out an integral, I'm using a series definition of associated Laguerre polynomials:

$$
L_\ell ^ \alpha (x) = \sum_{\mu = 0}^{\ell} 
\left( {\begin{array}{} \ell + \alpha \\ \ell - \mu \\ \end{array}} \right) \frac{(-x)^\mu}{\mu !}
$$

Since I need to square it but want to maintain its summation form, is this correct?

$$
\left[ L_\ell^\alpha (x) \right ]^2 = \sum_\nu^\ell \sum_\mu^\ell \left( {\begin{array}{*{10}c} \ell + \alpha \\ \ell - \mu \\ \end{array}} \right) \left( {\begin{array}{*{10}c} \ell + \alpha \\ \ell - \nu \\ \end{array}} \right) \frac{(-x)^{\mu+\nu}}{\mu!\nu!}
$$

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, if you have the sum
$$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^m a_i\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j\bigg)$$
This product of sums can be transformed into the double sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_i b_j$$
and thus the square of a sum
$$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^m a_i\bigg)^2$$
is equal to
$$\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m a_i a_j$$
So yes, what you've done should be correct.